# Set subtraction while casting lists and string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of strings. When I cast two lists into `set()` then subtraction works properly.

```
>>> A = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
>>> B = ['One']
>>> print(list(set(A) - set(B)))
['Three', 'Two', 'Four']
```

However when variable `B` is a string and I cast it into `set()` then, the subtraction is not working.

```
>>> A = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
>>> B = 'One'
>>> print(list(set(A) - set(B)))
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
```

Is anyone able to explain me if its a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: This is expected. It considers the string as an iterable and thus creates a set of all letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set()` function, when operating on a string, will generate a set of all characters:

```py
print(set("ABC"))  # set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
```

If you want a set with a single string `ABC` in it, then you need to pass a collection containing that string to `set()`:

```py
print(set(["ABC"]))  # set(['ABC'])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. It considers the string as an iterable and thus creates a set of all letters.

```
B = 'One'
set(B)
# {'O', 'e', 'n'}
```

You can clearly see it if you have letters in `A`:

```
A = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'O', 'o', 'n']
B = 'One'

print(list(set(A) - set(B)))
```

Output: `['o', 'Two', 'One', 'Four', 'Three']`